# Downloading A Large SQLite Database From Server in Binary vs. Creating It On The Device

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have an application that requires the creation and download of a significantly large SQLite database.  Depending on the user's data, creation of the db and the syncing of data from the server can take upwards of 20 to 25 minutes (some customers have a LOT of data).   The data is downloaded as JSON and processed with Android's built in JSON classes.

To account for OutOfMemory issues I was having with some devices, I needed to limit the per-call download from the server to 500 records at a time.  But, as of now, all of the above is working successfully - although slow.

Recently, there has been talk from my team of creating the complete SQLite db on the server side and then just downloading it to the device in binary in an effort to speed things up.   I've never done this before.  Is this indeed a viable option OR should I just be looking into speeding up the processing of the JSON through a 3rd party lib like GSON or Jackson.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: I assume you're already applying GZIP compression to the JSON while sending it to the Android client?

Comment: actually, no - this could certainly be an element of the overall solution if a faster JSON lib gets implemented.  But, alone, this won't help much as the bottleneck seems to be with the processing of the JSON records for inserting into the db.  Regardless, I'd really like to get some opinions on my original question prior to altering the existing implementation.  Thank you for the idea though Philipp.  I gave the comment and up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with mobile devices, reinventing synchronization is an overkill most of the time. It obviously depends on the hardware, software and amounts of data you're working with. But most of the time long operation execution times on mobile devices are caused by faulty design, careless coding or specifics of embedded systems not taken into consideration.

Unfortunately, I can only give you some hints which you may consider, given pretty vague description of issues you're facing. I mean "LOT" doesn't mean much to me - I've seen mobile apps with DBs containing millions of records running pretty smoothly and ones that had around a 1K records running horribly slow and causing UI to freeze. You also didn't mentioned what OS version and device (or at least it's capabilities) you're using. What's the server configuration, what software is installed, what libraries/frameworks are used and in what modes. It all matters when you want to really speed things up.

Apart of encoding being gzip (which I believe you left default, which is `on`), you should give this ideas a try:

1. Streaming! - make sure *both* the client and the server use a streaming version of JSON API and use buffered streams. If either doesn't - replace it with a library that does. Jackson has one of the fastest streaming API. Sure it's more cumbersome to write a (de)serializer, but it pays off. When done properly, none of the sides must create a buffer large enough for (de)serialization of all the data, fill it with contents, and then parse/write it. Instead, a much smaller buffer is allocated and filled gradually as successive fields are serialized. When this buffer gets filled, it's contents is immediately sent to the other end of data channel. There it can be deserialized right away. The process continues until all data have been transmitted in small chunks. It makes the data interchange much more fluent and less resource-intensive.
2. For large batch inserts or updates use prepared statements. It also sometimes helps to insert your data without constraints and then create them - that way, for example, an index can be computed in one run instead of for each insert. Don't use transactions (they require maintaining extra database logs) or commit every 300 rows to minimize the overhead. If you're updating existing database and atomic modifications are necessary - load new data to a temporary database and, if everything is ok, replace old database with new one on the fly.
3. Almost always some data can be precomputed and stored on an sd-card for example. Or it can be loaded directly to an sd-card as a prepared SQLite DB in the company. If a task requires data that is so large that an import takes more than 10 minutes, you probably shouldn't do that task on mobile devices in the first place.